# Symfony Templating inside service

Tags: symfony, service, twig, templating

I have defined a service which looks like:

```
namespace PrBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

class PrMailService extends \Twig_Extension{

   public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer,\Twig_Environment $twig )
{
    $this->twig = $twig;
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}

public function sendMail($messageSubject, $from, $to,$array)
{

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($messageSubject)
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setBody(
            $this->twig->render('PrBundle:Email:basic_email_template.html.twig',
                array(
                    $array
                )
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    $this->mailer->send($message);

}
```

In config.yml , I set the service as following:

```
services:    
  PrMailService:
      class: PrBundle\Service\PrMailService
      arguments: ["@mailer", "@templating"]
```

At least, I can't render the template app/console test:service, it dies wieth the following error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]Catchable Fatal Error: 
Argument 2 passed to PrBundle\Service\PrMailService::__construct() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, instance of Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Debug\TimedTwigEngine given.
```

In app/console container:debug, there is "templating" defined as TimedTwigEngine. This is confusing me a bit. Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: `@twig` instead of `@templating`

Comment: Are you planning on calling sendMail from within a twig template?  If not then it makes little sense to extend your service from Twig_Extension.

Comment: Cool thank you. this works perfekt. In documentation, always Templating will be listed :(